# Calling the failed function: 'should not be called statically' in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use version laravel 5.4

In `Helpers/Helper.php`

```
public function test()
{
  return 'success';
}
```

**In controller**

```
use App\Helpers\Helper;

public function index()
{
  $val = Helper::test();
  dd($val);
}
```

Error : **Helper::test() should not be called statically**

I called the function inside `helper` to use it. But got the error as above. Please show me how to get the function in `helper`. Thank you

Comment: define it as static? public static function test()... If it doesn't need access to "self/this" of the class - then you can declare it as a static function and use the same syntax you already have

Comment: You have made your function but you have not mentioned that it is static. So you need to change your method as static before calling using scope resolution operator

Comment: Does test method located inside a class named Helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the `test` function statically you must define it as a static function, like below. Otherwise, you would have to do something like `(new Helper())->test();` which is probably not something you want to do for a simple helper function that doesn't need to access `$this`. You can read a bit more about the use of static methods in the PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper
{
    public static function test()
    {
        return 'success';
    }
}
```